# passing variables to another page

Tags: php

i am trying to pass the `note_id` variable from index page to view_note_2 page but for some reason the variable is not going through i do not fully understand this can some one please help me out here and explain

index.php

```
$note_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `notes` WHERE `user_id` ='$my_id'");
while ($run_note = mysql_fetch_assoc($note_query))
        {
            $note_id = $run_note['id'];             
            echo "<a id='list_user' href='view_note_2.php?note=$note_id'><br>"; 
        }

?>
```

view_note_2.php

```
if(isset($_GET['note_id']) && !empty($_GET['note_id']))/* unable to get `note_id` */
        {
            $note_id=$_GET['note_id'];

            $note_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `notes` WHERE `id` ='$note_id'");
```

Comment: Maybe in the first script put brackets {} around the $note_id string in the echo statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change `$_GET['note_id']` to `$_GET['note']`.

Good luck

Answer (score 2):

You should start using a debugger (xdebug?), but since you are doing php is much simpler to start printing some variables and see what is going on.

For example, try to run this, and see the output on your error log. If you don't know what it is is or where it is, you may want to google about it.

```
$note_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `notes` WHERE `user_id` = $my_id");
while ($run_note = mysql_fetch_assoc($note_query)) {
    error_log('run_note:' . print_r($run_note, 1));
    $note_id = $run_note['id'];
    error_log('note_id:' . $note_id);
    echo "<a id='list_user' href='view_note_2.php?note=$note_id'><br>"; 
}
```

**NOTE:** As pointed out by other users you're using the GET variable `note` but you are referring to it as `note_id` so also change your code to this

```
if(isset($_GET['note']) && !empty($_GET['note'])) {
    $note_id=$_GET['note'];
    $note_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `notes` WHERE `id` =$note_id");
}
```

ps: you may want to escape the parameters that you use in the queries, otherwise you are exposed to sql injections. You can find more info with google, [this one](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-sql-injection.htm) is a good start

Answer (score 2):

The parameter name that the page gets is 'note', while in view_note_2.php you look for a parameter named 'note_id'. Also, I'd advise to protect your queries against SQL injection as for now anyone can inject any value to the 'note' parameter which is directly used in the query.